# Jest - [Function anonymous] in expect

Tags: javascript, jestjs

Jest expects the expected `Cell` property value to be `[Function anonymous]`.

What is correct syntax for that?

`() => {}` seems to be `[Function Cell]` thus test fails.

```
const expected =
      [{ Cell: () => {}, Header: '', accessor: () => {}, disableSortBy: true, id: 18, width: 50 }];

expect(result).toBe(expected);
```

Console:

```
 $ jest test

----
    - Expected  - 1
    + Received  + 1

    @@ -1,8 +1,8 @@
      Array [
        Object {
    -     "Cell": [Function Cell],
    +     "Cell": [Function anonymous],
          "Header": "",
          "accessor": [Function accessor],
          "disableSortBy": true,
          "id": 18,
          "width": 50,
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to tell that it expects array and then objects on it.
Each object needs to be specified its type or value

Try something like this

```js
const expected = expect.arrayContaining([
    expect.objectContaining({
      Cell: expect.any(Function),
      Header: expect.any(String),
      accessor: expect.any(Function),
      disableSortBy: expect.any(Boolean),
      /*...........so..on............*/
    })
  ]);

expect(result).toEqual(expected);
```

Comment: Your answer works with 1 item but if array contains two items it passes the test.
Like this result falsely passes when expected remains the same. 

```
[
        {
          Header: '',
          id: 18,
          accessor: [Function: accessor],
          width: 50,
          disableSortBy: true,
          Cell: [Function]
        },
        {
          Header: 'Project Created On',
          id: 15,
          accessor: [Function: accessor],
          width: NaN
        }
      ]
```

Comment: If you want to check every array element one by one then better to make a loop and compare to each object with 'expect'